# Angular2 format an array to fit to Google maps api lat lng type

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework

My service returns co-ordinates in following format:

for `this.exhibitionSurveyObjects[0].path` I get

```
[{"lat":52.52157422886321,"lng":13.400187492370605},{"lat":52.5232715010553,"lng":13.407654762268066},{"lat":52.52068639882502,"lng":13.4067964553833}]
```

For drawing polygon google maps api expects something like this:

```
var triangleCoords = [
          {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
          {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
          {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
          {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
        ];
```

How can I format my array to meet the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.exhibitionSurveyObjects.length; i++){

          this.exhibitionSurveyObjects[i].path = this.exhibitionSurveyObjects[i].path.replace(/"/g, "");

        }
```